# shred data into table by using xml

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I'm studying XML/SQL and have the following question. I would like to shred XML data into a table. but my question is: I have many authors using the same tag (`<author>`) inside the same book category. I would like to select ALL the authors, but I can't achieve this point. Could you please help me to do that?

The result should look like:

```
category    title              author             author1        author2
=============================================================================
CHILDREN    Harry Potter       J K. Rowling       NULL           NULL
WEB         XQuery Kick Start  James McGovern     Per Bothner    Kurt Cagle
```

Code:

```
declare @int int
declare @var xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
 <bookstore>

 <book category="CHILDREN">
   <title lang="en">Harry Potter</title>
   <author>J K. Rowling</author>
   <year>2005</year>
   <price>29.99</price>
 </book>

 <book category="WEB">
   <title lang="en">XQuery Kick Start</title>
   <author>James McGovern</author>
   <author>Per Bothner</author>
   <author>Kurt Cagle</author>
   <year>2003</year>
   <price>49.99</price>
 </book>

 </bookstore>';

EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @int OUTPUT, @var


SELECT
*
into MyTable
FROM
OPENXML(@int, 'bookstore/book', 11)
with
(
category varchar(100),
title varchar(100),
author varchar(100)
author1 varchar(100),
author2 varchar(100)
);
```

Comment: obs: i'm new at Stackoverflow, so I dont know how to format correctly my result table. I'm feeling sorry for that.

Comment: I don't know what the term "shred data into table" means.

Answer (score 2):

If you **know** that you'll never have more than 3 authors, you can use something like this:

```
SELECT
    XBook.value('@category', 'varchar(20)'),
    XBook.value('(title)[1]', 'varchar(50)'),
    XBook.value('(year)[1]', 'int'),
    XBook.value('(price)[1]', 'decimal(10,2)'),
    XBook.value('(author)[1]', 'varchar(50)'),
    XBook.value('(author)[2]', 'varchar(50)'),
    XBook.value('(author)[3]', 'varchar(50)')
FROM 
    @var.nodes('/bookstore/book') AS XTbl(XBook)
```

I personally find using the native XQuery support much easier than the old, *clunky* `OPENXML` approach (which also suffered from memory leaks and other deficiencies).

This gives you an output like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is one way...

```
SELECT
*
into MyTable
FROM
OPENXML(@int, 'bookstore/book', 11)
with
(
category varchar(100) '@category',
title varchar(100) 'title',
author varchar(100) 'author[1]',
author1 varchar(100) 'author[2]',
author2 varchar(100) 'author[3]'
);
```

And here is another way, with a different structure.

```
SELECT
*
into MyTable
FROM
OPENXML(@int, 'bookstore/book/author', 11)
with
(
category varchar(100) '../@category',
title varchar(100) '../title',
author varchar(100) '.'
);
```

Note that when you use the second method, you will get 4 rows with your sample data because the first book has 1 author while the second book has 3 authors.  Note that I changed the OPENXML line to start a little further down in the hierarchy.